# z-index with using slider module

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I normally don't post to forums, but I'm keen to understand why the red div on the right hand side (with text), will not appear on top of the white navigation bar. It always appears behind it.

I've played with position: relative/absolute on items using firebug, and set the z-index.. However it doesn't seem to make a difference and bring the red div to the front. I'm wondering if this is because javascript is involved?

Would appreciate some guidance on what's causing the layering issue and the potential CSS to fix the issue.

URL http://tinyurl.com/p445t34

Comment: `I normally don't post to forums`, same was the case with me until I found this, StackOverflow.

Comment: This isn't a forum...It's a Q&A site. You ask questions and get answers. Forums invite discussion, we don't.

Comment: Hope my answer was of some help. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

A parent element of the `<div>` you want to appear above (with id of "MS53c65ec22f27f" and class "master-slider") has been given a `z-index` of 0. This has set itself and its child elements below the white navigation bar which has been given a `z-index` of 1.

Because the Parent element is set behind the navigation, anything within the parent element is then on a separate layer no matter what the z-index is.

I don't think there's a simple way of fixing this with css. You would need to remove the `z-index` from the parent element or else give it the same or higher value than the navigation.

Ideally I think you'd need to re-order the html slightly.

Here is an ideal setup for the effect I think you're after.

Very basic setup of html:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="nav">nav</div>
    <div id="slide">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS which positions only the child elements with `z-index`.

```
#body{
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}

#nav{
    background-color:#eee;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#slide{
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#title{
    background-color:#900;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:30px;
    z-index:2;
}

#image{
    background-color:#999;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing the general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Vcb2N/1/

Because the `#slide` element is not given a z-index, the child elements remain in the same layer as the `#nav` element.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case. Unfortunately, the slider plugin outputs the image and slider in that position, and I can only insert my code around it. If I hack the plugin, I"ll lose my ability to update it in the future. I was hoping to be able to fix this with CSS, if it was a little lengthy in code.

Comment: @AdamKwiatkowski hmmm, thought that might be your problem. I think you may be stuck with that one. I'll have another look when I get the chance though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed this by seeing how slide dots can be visible.
The solution is to set a z-index >= 1 and to set the visibility css property to visible.

```
element {
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```